# Lower case words after hyphen in Python

Tags: python-3.x

When using `str.title()` the word after the hyphen is capitalised, but I don't want it to be. How can I capitalise only the first part?

```
Input:
I am james-bond

Expected output:
I am James-bond

---

Input:
I am James-Bond

Expected output:
I am James-bond
```

In both cases the output I actually get to `james-bond` is

```
James-Bond
```

Comment: there is no inbuilt function to set words after a hyphen to lower case. you would need to write your own function

Comment: If you need just a first letter in caps you can use capitalize()  method.  
Question:  Do you need only one word after hyphen(-) to be in lower case ?

Answer (score 0):

To convert every word followed by hyphen(-) to lower case, regular expressions can be used (re module).

Following code will convert every word followed by hyphen(-) to lower case

```
import re
s = 'Hello-I am James-Bond'
re.sub(r'(?<=-)\w+', lambda m: m.group().lower(), s)
```

Here the most important line is

> re.sub(**r'(?<=-)\w+'**, lambda m: m.group().lower(), s)

Regular expression **(?<=-)\w+** is doing the trick. It is called lookbehind assertion. Here it matches every word only if it is followed by hyphen(-)